# プロットの横軸が詰まって読めない

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

**試したコード**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips['total_bill'].plot.bar()
```

**結果**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記のように行数を制限すると読めています。

```
tips['total_bill'][:10].plot.bar()
```

**結果**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なにか良い方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaxNLocator` を使う方法です。

```py
ax = tips['total_bill'].plot.bar()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(len(tips)//20+1))
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score 1):

例えばこんな感じで元のX軸ラベルを取得して、同数の空文字列配列に10個おきに値をコピーして再設定すれば、間引いて表示されるので見易くなるでしょう。

```
ax = tips['total_bill'].plot.bar()
xlabels = ax.get_xticklabels()

newlabels = [''] * len(xlabels)
for i in range(0,len(xlabels),10):
    newlabels[i] = xlabels[i]

ax.set_xticklabels(newlabels)
```